# Find the best car deal

Tags: sqlite

The actual problem is about optimizing a cache database, I've re-phrased it into a simple scenario:

A car dealer wants to get rid of old cars, and lists them for sale in a table:

```
| Car_Number | Car_Year  | Car_Price |
|------------|-----------|-----------|
|1001........|1967.......|29000......|
|1002........|1930.......|29050......|
|1003........|2001.......|30000......|
|1004........|1980.......|10000......|
|1005........|1967.......|75000......|
|1006........|2005.......|80000......|
|1007........|1995.......|21000......|
|1008........|1920.......|55000......|
```

A customer wants to select maximum number of cars within a fixed budget, With older cars preferred over newer ones, or the cars with older number in case two cars have same year.

The only way I can currently think about this problem is obtaining a sorted view and manually adding up prices in a loop until the sum hits budget limit. Then, return a list of numbers of cars added.

what would be the minimal set of SQL commands required for above scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all cars that don't break the budget:

```
SELECT Car_Number, Car_Year
  FROM Cars c
 WHERE (SELECT SUM(Car_Price)
          FROM Cars
         WHERE Car_Year < c.Car_Year
            OR (Car_Year = c.Car_Year AND Car_Number <= c.Car_Number)
       ) <= :Budget
```

Comment: Thanks!. I'm trying to understand the first query here. For each Record in Car Table, you select that one, for which, the Sum of price of cars older or with smaller car number(in case year is same), less-than/equals the budget. Will not it return more that one records ? Shouldn't that be >= budget ?

Comment: @wingman: Ah, yes. I missed a beat there. To find the *first* car that breaks the budget is quite a bit trickier. I've amended the question. First I made a small change to find cars that *don't* break the budget (one of the `<`s became `<=`). This is unrelated to the problem you describe, but it deals with the edge-case whereby all cars are within budget. Then I added a clause that essentially repeats the outer query to find any cars *after* the one in question that *also* don't break the budget, which would exclude the current car (we only care about the *last* car that fits). Very messy.

Comment: @wingman: (Slaps forehead.) I just realised that it's much easier than I first thought. See my latest amendment.

Comment: Yes, The first query (same as updated one) you posted, listed all such scenarios, where if a particular car is the last (least preferred) in the shopping list, the deal still meets the budget.Now, I hope I'm correct here, from this scenario-list we got, we've to select the least preferred car, i.e the biggest shopping list scenario.